# Circuit Logic NAND

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have to build a circuit using only NAND gates. But I wasn't given an equation. Instead I was given this formula:

F(wxyz)= E m(0,1,2,3,4,5,7,14,15)

Function of (wxyz) = Sum m(0,1,2,3,4,5,7,14,15)

I have to get it down to terms of w,x,y, and z. So I'm pretty sure I make the binary truth table, and any number listed in the equation is where I put a 1. All other numbers (6,8,9,10,11,12,13) are 0. But from there, how do I get the equation so it's only NANDs?

---

*Edit by Willie*: I think this is what the OP meant to ask, rewritten in more familiar language, but will leave it to the OP to verify.

Consider the function $f:\{0,1\}^{4} \to \{0,1\}$ such that 
$$ f(w,x,y,z) = \begin{cases}
1 & 2^3 w + 2^2 x + 2^1 y + 2^0 z \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,7,14,15\} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$

How can one write $f$ purely in terms of compositions of the NAND function $g:\{0,1\}^2 \to \{0,1\}$ 
where
$$ g(u,v) = 1- uv $$

In other words, the OP is looking for an expression of $f$ as schematically
$$ f(w,x,y,z) \stackrel{?}{=} g(g(w,g(\dots)),g(\dots))$$

Comment: Well, basically, after creating the truth table, you just have to create a Karnaugh map. You will then have a simplified logical function from it, and try to re-write it using only NANDs by applying logical rules.

Comment: it is a logic question it only uses more the technical boolean logic names than the propositional logic terms

Answer (score 1):

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
wx, yz  & 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\ \hline
0 & 1  & 1  & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 1  & 1  & 1 &0\\ \hline
0 & 0  & 0  & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 0   & 0  & 0 & 0\\ \hline
\end{array}
Since we are dealing with NAND, we consider the zeros instead(hence the overall negation): $\overline{w\bar{y}+w\bar{x}+\bar{w}xy\bar{z}}=\left({\overline{w\bar{y}}}\right)\;\left({\overline{w\bar{x}}}\right)\left({\overline{\bar{w}xy\bar{z}}}\right)\qquad \leftarrow$ which can be implemented using NAND gates

Answer (score 0):

If you have a truth table, then you can just make a binary encoder made up of AND and NOT gates for each binary setting. AND is NOT(NAND) and NOT is a NAND gate with two inputs that are the same.